# Código imprime duas vezes mas deveria imprimir somente uma

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber porque é que na hora que executo o algoritmo, a linha que pede pra digitar o nome do aluno é impressa na tela 2 vezes.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Quando o tamanho do conjunto de alunos");
 int tamanho = input.nextInt();

 String[] alunos = new String[tamanho]; 
 for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
 {
    System.out.println("Digite o nome do aluno");
    alunos[i] = input.nextLine();
 }
```

Comment: Eu não sei o que foi pior, a edição que não melhora nada o texto ou a aprovação dessas edições extremamente simplistas que não não melhoram substancialmente o texto, talvez só para ganhar pontos.

Comment: @bigown o editor é novo no site, e eu até entendo que está editando de boa vontade. Em compensação, você pode perceber pelos históricos que é sempre o mesmo pessoal que aprova edição de qualquer jeito e não tá nem aí com a coisa, em vez de orientar os usuários novos.

Comment: @Bacco a intenção foi ressaltar isto mesmo :)

Answer (score 4):

Se você está respondendo à primeira pergunta com `1`, é porque seu loop roda uma vez para o zero, e outra para o um. Você precisa usar `<` em vez de `<=`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
```

E para cada aluno, em vez de pegar o que foi digitado você está pegando o resto da linha anterior. Use `next()` em vez de `nextLine()`:

```
alunos[i] = input.next();
```

E por que não criar uma lista do tamanho que você precisa?

```
String[] alunos = new String[TAMANHO];
```

Também seria recomendado não usar `TAMANHO` assim em caixa-alta, fica parecendo uma constante. Seria melhor usar `tamanho`.

Comment: Obrigado resolveu! :D poderia me dar uma breve explicação sobre essa diferença de nextLine para next?

Comment: @YgorRamos O newtLine move um cursor interno do Scanner pro fim da linha, e retorna o que estava antes dele. O next pede uma string e aceita quando você dá enter.

Comment: @YgorRamos nao marque "resolveu" na pergunta, basta clicar no V verdinho do lado da resposta para marcar como aceita, que o sistema já trata a questao como resolvida.